# Does .Net / C#'s speed degrade with increased field depth?

Tags: .net, object, performance, hierarchy, depth

Is there any execution speed difference between the following two lines of code? I cannot tell from looking at the IL:

```
int x = MainObject.Field1;
int x = MainObject.Public.Fields.Field1;
```

I know from Delphi (native code), there is no difference.

Comment: How can you not tell by the IL?  Both generate a **single**, practically identical, IL statement.

Comment: If those are non-trivial properties, there could be code of arbitrary complexity inside them, so it's not possible to say. If they are all reference-type fields, (simplifying things a bit) each  "nested" (non-null) reference must be dereferenced: the object it refers to will be on a different part of the heap. This will have a minor performance cost; in particular, it will not be cache-friendly. Not something likely to make any significant difference in most real-world apps.

Comment: @Ani - your comment is a *lot* more accurate than the marked answer.  You ought to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accesing by '.' to deeper class structure elements - NO, but method invocation with it - YES.

Comment: This question is meaningless in the context of method invocations.

Comment: Invocations:
int x = MainObject.Field1.ToString().Trim().Length;

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference whatsoever. (assuming you mean, as you say in the title, fields)